# Sitecore Commerce 9 Update 1 Installation Issue with SPE 4.7.2

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-commerce, powershell

I tried to install Sitecore Commerce using PowerShell script but I got the error that resource is not found for Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 4.7.2 although I have this zip package for Sitecore 9 version. Check my PowerShell output:

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: can you add to the question variable @params from your script

Comment: Regarding this issue, I managed to solve it. I am not sure how, but when I removed existing certificate and add new, I passed this step.